# Best way to count Greater Than in numpy 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

results is 2d numpy array with size 300000

```
for i in range(np.size(results,0)):  
     if results[i][0]>=0.7:  
        count+=1
```

it takes me 0.7 second in this python code,but I run this in C++ code,it takes less than 0.07 second.
So how to make this python code as fast as possible?

Answer (score 2):

When doing numerical computation for speed, especially in Python, you never want to use for loops if possible. Numpy is optimized for "vectorized" computation, so you want to pass off the work you'd typically do in for loops to special numpy indexing and functions like `where`.

I did a quick test on a 300,000 x 600 array of random values from 0 to 1 and found the following.

Your code, non-vectorized with one for loop: 
**226 ms per run**

```
%%timeit
count = 0
for i in range(np.size(n,0)):  
     if results[i][0]>=0.7:  
        count+=1
```

emilaz Solution: 
**8.36 ms per run**

```
%%timeit
first_col = results[:,0]
x = len(first_col[first_col>.7])
```

Ethan's Solution: 
**7.84 ms per run**

```
%%timeit
np.bincount(results[:,0]>=.7)[1]
```

Best I came up with 
**6.92 ms per run**

```
%%timeit
len(np.where(results[:,0] > 0.7)[0])
```

All 4 methods yielded the same answer, which for my data was 90,134. Hope this helps!

Comment: len(np.where(results[:,0] > 0.7)[0]), 0.0003s

Comment: Note that the results highly depend on the shape of your matrix, especially the length of the column you are iterating over. This can lead to a different ranking (see @bitnicks speed measurements below each answer)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
first_col=results[:,0]
res =len(first_col[first_col>.7])
```

Depending on the shape of your matrix, this can be 2-10 times faster than your approach.

Comment: glad I could help :) don't forget to mark your question as answered if this was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could give the following a try:

```
np.bincount(results[:,0]>=.7)[1]
```

Not sure it’s faster, but should produce the correct answer