# Counting number of elements greater than a certain value in a numy.ndarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I want to calculate the count of number of elements in a numpy.ndarry which is greater than a certain value. How do I get the required results?

For example:

```
[[0.25656927 0.31030828 0.23430803 0.25999823 0.20450112 0.19383106
  0.35779405 0.36355627 0.16837767 0.1933686  0.20630316 0.17804974
  0.06902786 0.26209944 0.21310201 0.12016498 0.14213449 0.16639964
  0.33461425 0.15897344 0.20293266 0.14630634 0.2509769  0.17211646
  0.3922994  0.14036047 0.12571093 0.25565785 0.18216616 0.0728473
  0.25328827 0.1476636  0.1873344  0.12253726 0.16082433 0.20678088
  0.33296013 0.03104548 0.14949016 0.05495472 0.1494042  0.32033417
  0.05361898 0.14325878 0.16196126 0.15796155 0.10990247 0.14499696]]
```

is the array and I want the count of number of elements greater than `0.19214945092486838`.
Here the value will be 21. How to calculate it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to count Greater Than in numpy 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55698337/best-way-to-count-greater-than-in-numpy-2d-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
import numpy

arr = numpy.asarray([0.25656927, 0.31030828, 0.23430803, 0.25999823, 0.20450112, 0.19383106, 0.35779405, 0.36355627, 0.16837767, 0.1933686,  0.20630316, 0.17804974, 0.06902786, 0.26209944, 0.21310201, 0.12016498, 0.14213449, 0.16639964, 0.33461425, 0.15897344, 0.20293266, 0.14630634, 0.2509769,  0.17211646, 0.3922994,  0.14036047, 0.12571093, 0.25565785, 0.18216616, 0.0728473, 0.25328827, 0.1476636,  0.1873344,  0.12253726, 0.16082433, 0.20678088, 0.33296013, 0.03104548, 0.14949016, 0.05495472, 0.1494042,  0.32033417, 0.05361898, 0.14325878, 0.16196126, 0.15796155, 0.10990247, 0.14499696])

print((arr > 0.19214945092486838).sum())
```

The output is: `21`

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing!

Comment: @Ray well, that's probably one of the cleanest way to achieve this (as far as I know)

Comment: This is possibly the easiest and fastest way to calculate it. Works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

`ar[ar>0.19214945092486838]` will provide you list of elements which are higher than the current values. You can take `len` to get the length

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ar = np.array([0.25656927,0.31030828,0.23430803,0.25999823,0.20450112,0.19383106,0.35779405,0.36355627,0.16837767,0.1933686,0.20630316,0.17804974    ,0.06902786,0.26209944,0.21310201,0.12016498,0.14213449,0.16639964,0.33461425,0.15897344,0.20293266,0.14630634,0.2509769,0.17211646    ,0.3922994,0.14036047,0.12571093,0.25565785,0.18216616,0.0728473,0.25328827,0.1476636,0.1873344,0.12253726,0.16082433,0.20678088    ,0.33296013,0.03104548,0.14949016,0.05495472,0.1494042,0.32033417,0.05361898,0.14325878,0.16196126,0.15796155,0.10990247,0.14499696])

>>> print(len(ar[ar>0.19214945092486838]))
>>> 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way

```
my_array = ... the target array ...
result = sum(0.19214945092486838 < x for x in my_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

With numpy you can try:

```
Myarray= [ [ your array]]
Value_to_search=0.19214945092486838

Array_greater_than=Myarray>Value_to_search
Nb_Val_greater_than=Array_greater_than.sum()
print(Nb_Val_greater_than)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an array of which the item is greater than / less than:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.arange(12)
>>> data > 5
array([False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True])
```

Then you just have to find the sum of the array:

```
>>> (data > 5).sum()
6
```

Now substitude `data` with your values, and use `(data > 0.19214945092486838)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet of code will achieve what you desire :)

```
import numpy as np
arrayToCheck=np.array([0.25656927, 0.31030828, 0.23430803, 0.25999823, 0.20450112, 0.19383106,
  0.35779405, 0.36355627, 0.16837767, 0.1933686,  0.20630316, 0.17804974,
  0.06902786, 0.26209944, 0.21310201, 0.12016498, 0.14213449, 0.16639964,
  0.33461425, 0.15897344, 0.20293266, 0.14630634, 0.2509769,  0.17211646,
  0.3922994,  0.14036047, 0.12571093, 0.25565785, 0.18216616, 0.0728473,
  0.25328827, 0.1476636,  0.1873344,  0.12253726, 0.16082433, 0.20678088,
  0.33296013, 0.03104548, 0.14949016, 0.05495472, 0.1494042,  0.32033417,
  0.05361898, 0.14325878, 0.16196126, 0.15796155, 0.10990247, 0.14499696])
print ("The number of float numbers above your threshold is " + str(np.sum(a>0.19214945092486838)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest way (IMHO):

`x > 1` will transform your array `x` into a boolean one, where elements larger than 1 are True. Then you can count the True values by `np.count_nonzero()`

Thus, `np.count_nonzero(x > 1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
arr=np.array([0.25656927,0.31030828,0.23430803,0.25999823,0.20450112,0.19383106,
  0.35779405, 0.36355627, 0.16837767, 0.1933686,  0.20630316, 0.17804974,
  0.06902786, 0.26209944, 0.21310201, 0.12016498, 0.14213449, 0.16639964,
  0.33461425, 0.15897344, 0.20293266, 0.14630634 ,0.2509769 , 0.17211646,
  0.3922994 , 0.14036047, 0.12571093, 0.25565785, 0.18216616, 0.0728473,
  0.25328827, 0.1476636 , 0.1873344 , 0.12253726, 0.16082433, 0.20678088,
  0.33296013, 0.03104548, 0.14949016, 0.05495472, 0.1494042 , 0.32033417,
  0.05361898, 0.14325878 ,0.16196126, 0.15796155, 0.10990247, 0.14499696])
```

Count:

```
arr[np.where(arr>0.19214945092486838)].shape[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use len to count results like this example:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[0.25656927,0.31030828,0.23430803,0.25999823,0.20450112,0.19383106,
  0.35779405, 0.36355627, 0.16837767, 0.1933686, 0.20630316, 0.17804974,
  0.06902786, 0.26209944, 0.21310201, 0.12016498, 0.14213449, 0.16639964,
  0.33461425, 0.15897344, 0.20293266, 0.14630634, 0.2509769,  0.17211646,
  0.3922994,  0.14036047, 0.12571093, 0.25565785, 0.18216616, 0.0728473,
  0.25328827, 0.1476636,  0.1873344,  0.12253726, 0.16082433, 0.20678088,
  0.33296013, 0.03104548, 0.14949016, 0.05495472, 0.1494042,  0.32033417,
  0.05361898, 0.14325878, 0.16196126, 0.15796155, 0.10990247, 0.14499696]])

n = len(matrix[matrix > 0.18])
print(n)
```